# Not sure why code isn't being read?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I can't work out why the code stops as soon as the user inputs either RecPrisim, TriPrisim or Cylinder the program stops, prints out some random numbers and closes. I'm just wondering if its because the variables need to be numbers but I tried do the same thing using Strings and I got errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Length;
    int Height;
    int Base;
    int Width;
    int UserChoice;
    int ObjectResult;

    int RecPrisim;
    int TriPrisim;
    int Cylinder;
    int TriResulta;

    RecPrisim = 1;
    TriPrisim = 1;
    Cylinder = 1;
    TriResulta = 1;

    cout << "Choose one: RecPrisim, TriPrisim or Cylinder." << endl;
    cin >> UserChoice;

    if (UserChoice = RecPrisim)
    {
        cout << "Enter Length, Width then Height.";
        cin >> Length;
        cin >> Width;
        cin >> Height;

        ObjectResult = Length*Width*Height;
        cout << ObjectResult;
    }
    else if (UserChoice = TriPrisim)
    {
        cout << "Enter Base, Height, Width, Length." << endl;
        cin >> Base;
        cin >> Height;
        cin >> Width;
        cin >> Length;

        ObjectResult = Base*Height / 2 * Width*Length;
        cout << ObjectResult;
    }
    else if (UserChoice = Cylinder)
    {
        cout << "Enter Radius and Length." << endl;
        cin >> Base;
        cin >> Height;

        ObjectResult = 3.1459*Base*Base*Height;
        cout << ObjectResult;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: use `==` instead of `=`!!

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings.

Comment: Nishant although that was one of the problems (ive only been doing C++ for two days) I also realised after I posted the question that I assigned 1 to the variables of TriPrisim ect and so typing in TryPrisim as the UserChoice wasn't going to work and instead I had to type in 1. Thanks for helping tho :D

Comment: any current compilers would warn you about this

Answer (score 4):

Use `==` instead of `=`.

In C++, C and many more languages `==` is for comparing values whereas `=` is for assigning values.

If you want to initialise a variable say `test` with value `val`, then you should use `test = val`.

But in `if` conditions you (generally) want to compare values using a comparison operator like following

- `==` for comparing whether LHS is equal to RHS
- `>` for comparing whether LHS is greater than RHS
- `<` for comparing whether LHS is smaller than RHS

Based on the values the operator will either return `true` or `false` and the `if` condition will either be executed or not.

Since, it seems in your case you want to compare the value of `UserChoice` with some other value for equality, you should use `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `==`, not the `=`.For example,
the code `if(a = 1)` will be always true no matter what value of a, because `if(1)` is always true. Only the code `if(a == 1)` is what you want. I hope this can help you.